# The implementation of deleting from the database does not work, I can not understand why

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, crud, sql-delete

I have an entity to work with the base

```
class Task
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $status;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getTitle(): ?string
    {
        return $this->title;
    }

    public function setTitle(string $title): self
    {
        $this->title = $title;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(?bool $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I also have a controller that works with crud of this object.
In which create, update, read are implemented, but deletion does not work

```
    /**
     * @Route("/delete/{id}", name="delete_task")
     * @param Task $id
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function delete(Task $id)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->remove($id);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('to_do_list');
    }
```

When deleting an object from the list, it produces this error

[image]

**How to solve this problem.**

**add**
[image]

Comment: How do you call that method? The message seems pretty clear, it expects a model (of type Task) while you give it a string as parameter. Maybe change `Task $id` to just `$id`

Comment: @kerbholz I added a second screenshot that shows what happens if you remove Task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this method, specify exactly what you expect to delete

```
    /**
     * @Route("/delete/{id}", name="delete_task")
     * @param $id
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $tasks = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Task::class)->find($id);
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->remove($tasks);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('to_do_list');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method too, specify exactly what you are deleting. I use this in my project

---

```
if($request->get("id_product_remove"))
   {
       $id = intval($request->get("id_product_remove"));

       $Product= $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Product::class)->find($id);
       $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $entityManager->remove($Product);
       $entityManager->flush();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to install `SensioFrameworkExtraBundle` and then Symfony will automatically turn your identifier into an entity.

Here is documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html

Comment: I have installed doctrine/annotations": "^1.8

Comment: Check this https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html